# Samsung SCX-3405F prints horizontal line every 2 inches

Tags: laser-printer

I am using a [Samsung SCX-3405F](http://www.samsung.com/hk_en/support/model/SCX-3405F/XSS) laser printer with Windows 7.  Every printed page has a horizontal line about every 2 inches.  Any suggestions on how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please edit your [question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) to include what research you've done on your own in attempt to answer your question.  Tell us what you've tried so far and specifically where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused by a roller with a diameter of 2/3.14 = .63". This is only approximate, with the same error as your 2" measurement.

The documentation does not seem to have much info about "repeating defects", but as the printer is a mono printer, the most likely culprit is the drum. This is the green or blue roller that for can see inside the toner cartridge. It is usually covered by a flap to protect it from light when it is out of the printer. If the drum gets exposed to light for too long, it loses sensitivity in the exposed area and that can cause your problem.

I suggest replacing the toner cartridge to see if that fixes your problem. If it doesn't, please attach a scan of the page so we can see just what's happening.